# PHP MySQL Error column name does not exist in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql

```
$select = rtrim(trim('SELECT'.
                 (isset($_REQUEST['lName']) ? ' lName,' : '').
                 (isset($_REQUEST['fName']) ? ' fName,' : '').
                 (isset($_REQUEST['address']) ? ' address,' : '').
                 (isset($_REQUEST['email']) ? ' email,' : '').
                 (isset($_REQUEST['number']) ? ' contactNum,' : '').
                 (isset($_REQUEST['major']) ? ' major,' : '').
                 (isset($_REQUEST['gpa']) ? ' gpa,' : '').
                 (isset($_REQUEST['year']) ? ' academicYear,' : '').
                 (isset($_REQUEST['credits']) ? ' totalCredits' : '')),',');

        $where = strlen(trim($_REQUEST['whereQ'])) != 0 ? " WHERE ".$_REQUEST['whereQ'].";" : ";";

        print $select." FROM Student".$where."<br>";

    $result = mysql_query($select."FROM Student".$where,$con) or die("Could not perform query: ".mysql_error());

    while($data = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
        foreach($data as $col) {
            echo $col." ";
        }
    }

    mysql_close();
```

So heres my scenario. I run the code above on a local database but what i get back is an error saying that the database does not contain the column name for which I am asking for. But the problem is that it exists. Whats wrong here? Is there something with the code? Maybe the way the strings concatenate. :( help.

Comment: Make sure that the column name doesn't have any extra space in database and also MySQL is deprecated use `MySQLi` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: Can you put the query sql here?

Comment: What is your where condition ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see how here you have a space before "FROM"

```
print $select." FROM Student".$where."<br>"
```

and here you dont

```
mysql_query($select."FROM Student".$where,$con)
```

and its really bad practice to use `WHERE ".$_REQUEST['whereQ']` - [sql injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Comment: im telling you, no matter how much code I write, things like this always happen haha. This resolved this issue. Thank you all so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Is't your HTML like this:

```
<input name="whereQ" value="name=....">
```